# how to show convergence and evaluate $n\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{e^{-n/k}}{k^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-sum, exponential-sum

I tried this :
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}n\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{e^{-n/k}}{k^2} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2} dx$$ to evaluate, and to show convergence, I think $$n\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{e^{-n/k}}{k^2} < \sum_{k>1}{} \frac{1}{k^2}$$ which converges.

Comment: The term with $k=0$ does not make sense.

Comment: @Gary you are right it's $k = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
n\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {\frac{{e^{ - \frac{n}{k}} }}{{k^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{2n}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {\frac{{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}\frac{{2n}}{k}} }}{{(k/2n)^2 }}}  \to \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 {\frac{{e^{ - 1/(2x)} }}{{x^2 }}dx} \mathop  = \limits^{t = 1/(2x)} \int_{1/2}^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} dt}  = e^{ - 1/2} .
$$